# Angular 2 Tour of Heroes project not working after splitting appcomponent

Tags: typescript, angular

I've been following the tutorial to learn Angular 2, everything went well until I had to split up appcomponent into heroescomponent & appcomponent.

Anyone here that had the same problem or can see the problem?

app.component.ts

```
import { Component }       from 'angular2/core';
import { HeroService }     from './hero.service';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes.component';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {DashboardComponent} from './dashboard.component';
import {HeroDetailComponent} from "./hero-detail.component";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <nav
            <a [routerLink]="['Dashboard']">Dashboard</a>
            <a [routerLink]="['Heroes']">Heroes</a>
        </nav>

        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      `,

    styleUrls: ['app/app.component.css'],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        HeroService
    ]
})

@RouteConfig([
    {
        path: '/heroes',
        name: 'Heroes',
        component: HeroesComponent
    },
    {
        path: '/dashboard',
        name: 'Dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        useAsDefault: true
    },
    {
        path: '/detail/:id',
        name: 'HeroDetail',
        component: HeroDetailComponent
    }
])

export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Tour of Heroes';
}
```

heroes.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {Hero} from './hero';
import {HeroDetailComponent} from './hero-detail.component';
import {HeroService} from './hero.service';
import {Router} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-heroes',
    templateUrl: 'app/heroes.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/heroes.component.css'],
    directives: [HeroDetailComponent]
})

export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit{
    heroes: Hero[];
    selectedHero: Hero;

    constructor(
        private _heroService: HeroService,
        private _router: Router
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getHeroes();
    }

    getHeroes() {
        this._heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
    }

    onSelect(hero: Hero) {
        this.selectedHero = hero;
    }

    gotoDetail() {
        this._router.navigate(['HeroDetail', { id: this.selectedHero.id}]);
    }
}
```

main.ts

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component.ts'

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

[Tour of Heroes Part 5: Splitting the appcomponent](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html#!#splitting-the-appcomponent-)

Comment: Is there an error on the console?

Comment: can you post a plnkr?

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the closing ">" in the **nav opening tag**.

It should be

```
        <nav>
            <a [routerLink]="['Dashboard']">Dashboard</a>
            <a [routerLink]="['Heroes']">Heroes</a>
        </nav>
```

Instead of

```
        <nav
            <a [routerLink]="['Dashboard']">Dashboard</a>
            <a [routerLink]="['Heroes']">Heroes</a>
        </nav>
```

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/q17gPJjPU5XwyD1YRxA3?p=preview)

Comment: wow, didn't see that one at all, thx! But the project is still not displaying the website.

Comment: I made a plunker using your code.  It seems it is working, the error could be on another file.  [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/q17gPJjPU5XwyD1YRxA3?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you still have the issue but I encountered the same behaviour at the same step.

After some minutes searching why my component is not loading, due to code refactoring on the AppComponent (changed to HeroesComponent) it renamed it also in main.ts.

Refactoring did:

```
import {bootstrap} from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import {HeroesComponent} from "./heroes.component";

bootstrap(HeroesComponent);
```

Where you can see that your are not referencing the right component.

I changed it to

```
import {bootstrap} from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Et voilà, the app is loading again.

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've also lost contact with my previously well behaved tutorial tour of heroes application in the routing chapter. My previous problems have been solved by looking that the http response codes, but it's 304s and 200s down the line.

Is there a better approach to troubleshooting this thing than checking all of my elements for close angle brackets? It seems to be perfectly happy to just present me with a white rectangle with "Loading AppComponent content here ..." written in the upper left corner. Is there a log somewhere that would tell me what is going on?

Comment: It's client side code! The errors show up in the Chrome debugger (F12). I didn't think of this at first because the Page Source is just "
  <body><script id="__bs_script__">//<![CDATA[
    document.write("<script async src='/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.js?v=2.18.2'><\/script>".replace("HOST", location.hostname));
//]]></script>" but the Chrome debugger works great.